# std library equivalent to boost::upgrade_lock and boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock

Tags: c++, boost, std, locks

I have just been giving the task of deleting boost dependencies with the std library. I have come across upgrade_lock and upgrade_to_unique_lock and was wondering if there is a equivalent std library class?

Comment: Hmm... does it actually do anything useful? Wouldn't just releasing the `shared_lock` and making a new `unique_lock` do the job?

Comment: @ALX23z I think it stops some other thread from acquiring exclusive ownership whilst you want to switch from shared to exclusive or vice-versa

Comment: @Caleth but it is dangerous. As trying to make two such simultaneously results in deadlock. I suppose this is the reason why standart shied away from such feature.

Comment: @ALX23z I hate people who assume they know all use cases for a concept they here the first time. It is very useful in practice and almost all databases need it for performance.

Answer (score 3):

The initial proposal [N3568](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3568.html) by Howard Hinnant that proposed `shared_mutex` also contained a proposal for `upgrade_mutex` which fills exactly that gap.
However the concurrency subgroup spoke against the introduction of `upgrade_mutex` into C++14.
Consequently Howard wrote [N3569](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3659.html) which only includes `shared_mutex`. That proposal was accepted into C++17.

Howard gives more detailed reasons for the removal [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42847173) and also states that he is not going to invest the time and energy needed to get `upgrade_mutex` standardized. As likely as sadly it will never be standardized.

Usually I would recommend using Boost for this. Since you explicitly want to replace Boost there are not too many options left.

One is using means provided by your target operating system which is non-portable and probably not what you want. This becomes easier if your implementation of `<mutex>` provides [`std::mutex::native_handle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/native_handle).

You could also write your own solution, for that have a look at Howard's [reference implementation of `upgrade_mutex`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/upgrade_mutex). Note that you cannot combine that with the std::lib directly since N3568 would have added seven constructors to `std::unique_lock` which user code obviously cannot do. Hence you would need to clone a suitably licensed implementation of `<mutex>` into your own namespace, combine it with the reference implementation and then add those constructors to `unique_lock` that you actually need.

Comment: Just a note for others who find this (very nice) answer. There are some good non-`std` implementations of upgradable mutexes, such as [folly::SharedMutex](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/06911acf0b45c06e1302c8e04a1cb8ce2784dd02/folly/SharedMutex.h), worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

From cppreference on `shared_mutex`:

> Shared mutexes do not support direct transition from shared to unique ownership mode: the shared lock has to be relinquished with unlock_shared() before exclusive ownership may be obtained with lock(). boost::upgrade_mutex may be used for this purpose.

So no.